# Is it possible to use a BITAND nested in a DECODE

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to use BITAND in a DECODE or is there a better way to go about it. I'm trying:

```
AND DECODE(p_single, 'Y', BITAND( 16384, order_attributes_indicator) != 16384, 'N')
```

However, that is giving me an error. I want to check a value, if it is 'y', then do the BITAND statement. This is inside a cursor.

Comment: Your `decode()` doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use case:

```
AND case when ((p_single = 'Y') and (BITAND( 16384, order_attributes_indicator) != 16384)) then 1 end = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `case`.  Your logic doesn't make sense, but I'm thnking:

```
(case when p_single = BITAND(16384, order_attributes_indicator) 
      then 'Y' else 'N'
 end)
```

Or, this seems to be in a `WHERE` clause:

```
( (p_single = 'Y' and BITAND(16384, order_attributes_indicator) ) or
  (p_single <> 'Y')
)
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your response. I want a statement then checks if p_single = y then add the statement `AND BITAND( 16384, order_attributes_indicator) != 16384`

Comment: @RobBlagg . . . That is what the second version does.